# Dismissing two modal view controllers

Tags: ios, controller, transition

I have found several questions about this but the answers do not resolve my problem.

I have two controllers that I have presented using presentModalViewController.

I added modalTransitionStyle to the first controller that is called by Main Controller. The first controller presented the second controller normally (without transition style).

```
FirstVC *first = [[FirstVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstVC" bundle:nil];
first.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentModalViewController:first animated:YES];

SecondVC *second = [[SecondVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondVC" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
```

This is the code I used to go to the MainVC:

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And this is what happened:

[image]

The page didn't uncurl. What's the reason I'm encountering this?

Answer (score 6):

In my experiments, it appears you can't have a standard presentation (cover vertical) after a partial curl, and dismiss them both at the same time, unless you do the dismissal with the animation set to NO.

A way to fix this though is to dismiss secondVC with no animation (this code is in secondVC):

```
-(IBAction)dismissSelf:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Then in the firstVC dismiss again in viewDidAppear with animation, after testing that the controller is not being presented:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (![self isBeingPresented]) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

While the above code works to get back to the initial controller's view, you will see firstVC's view appear before the curl uncurls. If you don't want to see that, then the only way I could find to fix that, was to create an image of secondVC, add that as (in an image view) a subview to firstVC before doing the dismissal of secondVC. So, to do that, the code in secondVC should be this instead (note that you have to link to QuartzCore and import it into secondVC for this to work):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UIImage *img = [self imageWithView:self.view];
    FirstViewController *first = (FirstViewController *)self.presentingViewController;
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:first.view.bounds];
    iv.image = img;
    [first.view addSubview:iv];
}


-(IBAction)dismissSelf:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}


- (UIImage *)imageWithView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Comment: I have successfully resolved the problem by using [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BACKTOMAIN" object:nil];}]; Then in the receiving controller, I added [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; Thank you for answer also :)

Answer (score 3):

You should present your two views one after the other, with this call:

```
[self presentViewController:firstViewController animated:YES completion:^(
    [self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:^(

    }];
}];
```

this should behave better.  Also, know that you will have to pull both of those viewControllers off afterwards.

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}];
```

Comment: thanks for answering. But the second view controller will be called only after clicking a button inside the view of first controller.

Comment: ahh, then just make sure you pull them both off after the end.

Comment: Hi HalR, your answer helped me. What I did was to post a notification inside the completion block. `code`[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BACKTOMAIN" object:nil];}];

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are dismissing 'first' without dismissing 'second.'

The Apple recommended way of doing this is with delegation.

Try making the mainVC a delegate of 'first' so that first can call a method of mainVC to dismiss itself. Do this by declaring a 'delegate' property of 'first' and setting it to mainVC when 'first' is instantiated. then define a 'firstDelegate' protocol in first.h which includes some function like 'dismissFirst' and then import first.h in mainVC. now implement dismissFirst in mainVC to actually dismiss 'first' and do whatever else you want now that first is done being displayed.

gasp... now make 'first' a delegate of 'second' in the same way, and just make the 'dismissSecond' function call the 'dismissFirst' function of mainVC and all will be right with the world.

I know this is kindo complicated but delegation is a core iOS concept and this is the quintessential example of where it is used.

Here is a good explanation of how this works.
http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-iOS--Day-6%E2%80%93The-Delegate-Pattern

And I wish you the best of luck in your never ending quest to understand the inner machinations of an Apple engineer's mind also known as Obj-C.

Comment: It's fine to dismiss multiple controllers that have presented each other in a chain. If you dismiss the first one in the chain, all the others are dismissed. In this specific case, the problem results from  the presentation styles screwing that up.

Comment: I have resolved the problem by using the code given by HalR and some modification. I added a notification to dismiss the other controller.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same doubt. I resolved with some other way -

Step 1 : In a global class(singleton) you can define a variable flag.

```
@property (nonatomic) int flag;
```

Step 2 : Suppose you need to dismiss `second view controller` and `first view controller` and return back to the `Main view controller` , while dismissing the second view controller you can set this value as **suppose 1**.

```
[[Global sharedObject] setFlag:1];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Step 3 : In you `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method of the `first view controller` you can set this method -

```
if([[Global sharedObject] flag] == 1)
{
    [[Global sharedObject] setFlag:0];
    [self performSelector:@selector(back) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}

- (void) back
{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I hope your answer is solved using this. If you still have doubts, you could ask. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIViewController*)topViewController
{
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }
    return topController;
}


- (void)dismissAllModalController{

    __block UIViewController *topController = [self topViewController];

    while (topController.presentingViewController) {
        [topController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

        }];
        topController = [self topViewController];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `unwind segue`. Create an "empty" IBAction in the view controller you want to segue To.

```
@IBAction func unwindToController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

Then go to your storyboard and select the controller that you want to come From. In the icons at the top of a selected controller, the leftmost should be a yellow circle with a small white square at the center, aka the file owner. Ctrl-Drag to the "Exit" label of the view controller you want to unwind to. The Exit can be found near the bottom of the controllers trees, or on the Storyboard as the right most red square image with the white square w/right arrow in it. That will popup a dialog, select the `unwindToController` action you created.

A new "Unwind segue to Exit" will appear in your FROM controller. Double click it and give it an identifier, e.g. `unwindIdentifier`

Now when you want to unwind two controller, in your FROM controller, use:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindIdentifier", sender:nil)
```

That will skip the middle controller and unwind to the second one, showing only the TO controller in the animation.